# What version of emacs should I install on my Lubuntu computer?

Tags: linux, emacs, lubuntu

There are two versions of Emacs 24. With and without GTK+ interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on whether you want a GTK GUI or not. Either will work, but the GTK one will need the GTK libraries installed which you might not want (but probably do).

So, basically, if you a re running a minimal LXDE system and don't want any bloat use the non GTK. If you want things to be prettier, use the GTK.